# Flask app deployed on Heroku threading problem

Tags: python, flask, heroku, python-multithreading

I wrote a Flask application that needs a secondary thread to display a video stream in the browser.
Here is the way the thread is created:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # # start a thread that will perform motion detection
    t = threading.Thread(target=prepare_video_stream)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()

    print(t.is_alive())

    app.run(debug=True, threaded=True, use_reloader=False)
```

Everything works fine when a run my application with the built-in flask server, but after deploying to heroku with gunicorn the thread doesn't seem to start.
Here is my Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn app:app
```

How can I make the thread run? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I found a [solution to this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63749492/2217801)

The key is to run your thread in `@app.before _first_request` instead of the name locked `__main__`

```py
@app.before_first_request
def thread_start():
    # # start a thread that will perform motion detection
    t = threading.Thread(target=prepare_video_stream)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
    print(t.is_alive())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, threaded=True, use_reloader=False)
```